# How to fix random Fedora 37 freezes?

Tags: fedora, drivers, nvidia, freeze

I am running dual boot with Windows 11 and Fedora 37 GNOME 43, on kernel version 6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64

Before I installed fedora, I was using Ubuntu 20 and I never had any freezing problems at all. Now that I installed Fedora, I am getting these random freezes where everything is frozen, the mouse isn't moving, I can't open anything and basically have to turn off my laptop using a button.

Sometimes these freezes don't happen for a day, sometimes multiple freezes in an hour and nothing is triggered by a program because they happen even when every program is closed and I'm just on my Desktop.

Here is my entire `neofetch` command result:

```
         .';:cccccccccccc:;,.            --------------------- 
      .;cccccccccccccccccccccc;.         OS: Fedora Linux 37 (Workstation Editi 
    .:cccccccccccccccccccccccccc:.       Host: 81WE IdeaPad 3 15IIL05 
  .;ccccccccccccc;.:dddl:.;ccccccc;.     Kernel: 6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64 
 .:ccccccccccccc;OWMKOOXMWd;ccccccc:.    Uptime: 6 mins 
.:ccccccccccccc;KMMc;cc;xMMc:ccccccc:.   Packages: 1703 (rpm), 8 (flatpak) 
,cccccccccccccc;MMM.;cc;;WW::cccccccc,   Shell: bash 5.2.15 
:cccccccccccccc;MMM.;cccccccccccccccc:   Resolution: 1920x1080 
:ccccccc;oxOOOo;MMM0OOk.;cccccccccccc:   DE: GNOME 43.2 
cccccc:0MMKxdd:;MMMkddc.;cccccccccccc;   WM: Mutter 
ccccc:XM0';cccc;MMM.;cccccccccccccccc'   WM Theme: Adwaita 
ccccc;MMo;ccccc;MMW.;ccccccccccccccc;    Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
ccccc;0MNc.ccc.xMMd:ccccccccccccccc;     Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
cccccc;dNMWXXXWM0::cccccccccccccc:,      Terminal: gnome-terminal 
cccccccc;.:odl:.;cccccccccccccc:,.       CPU: Intel i5-1035G1 (8) @ 3.600GHz 
:cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc:'.         GPU: Intel Iris Plus Graphics G1 
.:cccccccccccccccccccccc:;,..            GPU: NVIDIA GeForce MX330 
  '::cccccccccccccc::;,.                 Memory: 2299MiB / 11519MiB
```

Do I downgrade the kernel because the kernel on ubuntu was 5. something? What do I downgrade it to? Is there some other solution to this?

This is the result of my `lspci` command:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G1 (Ice Lake) (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Processor Power and Thermal Controller (rev 03)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP DRAM Controller (rev 30)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Management Engine (rev 30)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 30)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 34b4 (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX330] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5008 (rev 01)
```

And I am using the nouveau driver which I read somewhere could be a problem.

```
lsmod | grep nouveau
nouveau              2703360  1
drm_ttm_helper         16384  1 nouveau
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
drm_display_helper    180224  2 i915,nouveau
ttm                    94208  3 drm_ttm_helper,i915,nouveau
wmi                    45056  5 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof,ideapad_laptop,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  65536  3 ideapad_laptop,i915,nouveau
```

Comment: I just realized that filling RAM to %100 causes this. In my case, it was vscode and some development tools, they allocate enormous amount of ram and use %100 swap & memory so fedora starts freezing. You can try, open System Monitor and make it Always on Top by right clicking the title bar. And watch the memory.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Fedora 37 with Nvidia proprietary drivers. System freezes frequently, sometimes in couple of hours. If I'm at the computer by the time of the crash I can catch the full behavior that is always same -- first mouse movement becomes slow then if stops moving at all. It takes a second or so from that slowdown beginning to complete stop i.e. it is not immediate crash.

When mouse stops the system is totally dead. No reaction to keyboard, no response to pings over the network, nothing. Only way out is power cycle with power button.

Some periodic updates make it last longer, some make it worse but it is here since I've upgraded from F36 to F37. That made worse than even early windozes, almost impossible to work.

Nothing in the logs.

Comment: Same with Fedora 36 & Fedora 38. Very very annoying. Nvidia drivers installed on laptop. It is probably a GPU related issue, maybe driver maybe kernel stuff idk. We are in 2023 and it still happens.

Comment: For my it looks like my swap and ram are filling up and fedora doesn't clear it up correctly so we just get a hardlock. Looking into increasing my swap but I think stuff's not getting cleared correctly because I certainly shouldn't be using 16GB of ram and 8GB swap just watching a youtube video, messaging apps and another firefox window.

Answer (score 1):

Crashes are most likely caused by the nouveau open source NVIDIA driver.

To solve the issue you need to install NVIDIA binary drivers: https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/NVIDIA Maybe Ubuntu installed it for you automatically, Fedora doesn't.